# merge_sort works and not works in some condition(input number)

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have this c code for merge sort.
The code works well when N<=4 but does not when N>4.
If I put in 4 for N and enter 4 numbers, the result shows as it should.
However, when I put in 6 and enter 6 numbers, the program stops for few seconds and puts out nothing as result. 
What can I do to make this code work for all occasions(N

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100000
void Merge(int* arr, int p, int q, int r);
void MergeSort(int *arr,int p, int r);
int main(void)
{
    int N, i;
    int *arr ;

    scanf("%d", &N);

    if ((N>MAX) || (N<1))
        return -1;

    arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);



    for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    MergeSort(arr, 0, N - 1);

    for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);

    free(arr);
}

void Merge(int *arr, int left, int mid, int right)
{
    int i,i1,i2;
    int b[right-left+1];

    for(i=left, i1=left, i2=mid+1;i<=right && i1<=mid && i2<=right;i++ ){
        if(arr[i1]>arr[i2])
            b[i]=arr[i1++];
        else
            b[i]=arr[i2++];
    }
    for(i; i<=right;i++){

        if(i1<=mid)
            b[i]=arr[i1++];
        if(i2<=right)
            b[i]=arr[i2++];
    }
    for(i=left;i<=right;i++)
        arr[i] = b[i];
}

void MergeSort(int *arr, int left, int right)
{
    int mid;

    if (left<right){

        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        MergeSort(arr, left, mid);
        MergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right);
        Merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also, please only use the language tags that you're programming in.

Comment: What does condition `i<=right` mean in `Merge` function?

Comment: The `i;` in `for (i; i <= right; i++) {` serves no purpose.  Review this code.

Comment: The first index of `b` that `Merge` uses is `left`.  It should be `0`.  So you're skipping the first part of `b`, then indexing past the end of it (the maximum index should be `right - left`).  You need to use `i - left` as the index into `b`.

Comment: The issue is with the Merge function. You just have one temp array `b` to copy the left and the right sides of the array for merging later on. This leads to a complicated `for` loop which is difficult to debug. 
Use two temporary arrays for left and right sides. This will make the `for` loops and the merging of the arrays simple.

Comment: I have tested the code with various inputs N>4, its working fine. I see that you are actually sorting the array in descending order due to condition "if(arr[i1]>arr[i2])" in your merge function.